# Passing values from python to html with django in views.py does not work

Tags: python, django

Hello I am following a django tutorial and the tutorial (FreeCodeCamp btw, they deserve to be noticed more) showed how to make a simple word counter in django. Now the thing is: While rendering the html file he passes some data to it like this:

```
def counter(request):
    words = request.GET['text']
    numberOfWords = len(words.split())
    return render(request, 'counter.html', {'amount_of_words': int(numberOfWords)})
```

(I noticed that after publishing it seems like there is not the right spacing for functions, there actually is)
[Screenshot of the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMHTB.png)

For the youtuber it works really fine, but for me it seems there is no way to display the data. in the html file i put this:

```
the number of words is {{amount_of_words}}
```

Which is exactly the same thing the tutorial guy did. Even if I add proper html boilerplate it doesn't seem to work

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index , name='index'),
    path('counter', views.counter, name="counter")
]
```

this is the urls.py file inside the app folder.

When loading counter it just shows "the message the number of words is " without display the value i pass from views.py

Even with a super simple example like this:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    person_name = {
        'name': 'John',
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', person_name)
```

index.html code:

```
<h1>ciao {{name}}</h1>
```

url when i load the page: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I don't get why it would not work for me.

Comment: Can you please add the error you are getting? What is the actual output right now?

Comment: I am not getting an error, where there should be the value, it is just blank

Comment: Please add the URL your requesting and the HTML you see in your browser

Comment: i loaded the urls.py's code and described what i see when i try the word counter

Comment: Please provide the exact URL you see in your browser if you load the page

Comment: Done, I provided th one of another project I tried running, I thought that maybe starting a new project would fix this and that just that project was bugged somehow but apparently in any project i run the issue persists

Comment: The adding a whitespace after/before the curly brackets `<h1>ciao {{ name }}</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Your request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` is missing the path to your view as well as the GET parameter.

Try: http://127.0.0.1:8000/counter?text=Test

Answer (score -1):

```
def counter(request):
    words = request.GET['text']
    numberOfWords = len(words.split())
    amount_of_words = int(numberOfWords)
    context = {
        'amount_of_words': amount_of_words,
    }
    return render(request, 'counter.html', context)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I have tried the context method too before making the question. Thanks for the reply though!